# Как перерисовать интерфейс WPF-приложения после изменения масштаба Windows

Tags: c#, wpf

При любом масштабе в Windows (100%, 125% и т.д.) шрифты и графика запускаемого WPF приложения отображаются чётко. Но если сменить масштаб в Windows при запущенном WPF приложении, то шрифты и графика становятся нечёткими, при этом, в неклиентской области окна отображение чёткое всегда. Если приложение перезапустить заново, то всё снова чётко отображается.

Хочется, если это возможно, что бы при изменении масштаба в Windows, запущенное приложение как то заново перерисовывалось для нормального чёткого отображения.

Вопроса вытекает два:

1. Можно ли как то отследить событие изменения масштаба Windows в C#?
2. Можно ли как то обновить/перерисовать/перезагрузить весь интерфейс приложения заново?

Пробовал для mainWindow вызывать InvalidateVisual() и UpdateLayout() - не помогает.

Comment: Быть может проще перезапустить приложение? Програмно.

Comment: В чём то проще конечно, но тогда придётся сохранять всю рабочую сессию приложения, а это сейчас не предусмотрено..

Comment: Я эту проблему наблюдал во многих приложениях, даже в тех, которые делал сам Microsoft. Изменение размера шрифта виндой - по факту не такая частая операция, в которую стоило бы вкладывать силы. В большинстве случаев оно не происходит никогда.

Comment: Согласен, по большому счёту это вопрос перфекционизма, просто если найдётся элегантное решение - хорошо, если нет, то и не принципиально в общем.

Comment: У меня нет под рукой виндовой машины что бы проверить. Но, не вызывается ли события ресайза окна/контрола при смене масштаба?

Comment: Может быть, но гораздо важнее отрендерить заново приложение.

Comment: Кстати, заметил ещё один момент: у меня в приложении есть открытие дочернего окна, так вот, когда при запущенном приложении изменить масштаб, соответственно шрифты все размываются, потом открываю это дочернее окно (создаётся через new и  вызывается метод show) и в нём тоже всё нечётко..

Comment: Артём Оконечников, я пробовал вручную менять размеры, сворачивать/разворачивать - результата нет, всё остаётся размыто, помогает только перезапуск всего приложения.

Comment: Может быть, [тут](https://github.com/microsoft/WPF-Samples/blob/master/PerMonitorDPI/readme.md) найдётся что-то полезное.

Comment: VladD, да очень похоже, спасибо, буду разбираться.